# The necessity to memset with '\0', in a toy example

Tags: c, memset

I encountered the following example of using memset in [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char src[40];
    char dest[100];

    memset(dest, '\0', sizeof(dest));
    strcpy(src, "This is tutorialspoint.com");
    strcpy(dest, src);

    printf("Final copied string : %s\n", dest);

    return(0);
}
```

I don't get why the memset line is used, as the compile and result are the same when that line is commented. I would like to ask is that line necessary? or is it a good practice to do so when doing strcpy()? or it is just one random line.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not needed here.

Comment: It is not needed but is an example of initializing a memory region before you use it. In this case it doesn't matter since the `strcpy` will append a null after the copy.

Comment: Some people just like being cautious with their variables so that they don't risk dealing with uninitialized data. It's a bit paranoid IMO, but it's not like it has no merit at all. In this particular case it seems a bit extreme, though.

Comment: Get it, thank you all.

Comment: Not needed in this example, but could be useful if other more complex operations were done on the string in `dest`. Usually it's better to define it as `char dest[100] = { '\0' };`.

Comment: One salient point is that local variables are not initialised, except by you.

Comment: That seems like an outdated concept. Such arrays should be initialized with { 0 }.

Comment: Note: it is not needed in this example *because strcpy copies the null terminator as well*. If you used memcpy to copy just the non-null bytes of the string, for example, you could end up with the string followed by random values in `dest`.

Comment: @2501: If you mean that the programmer should initialize such arrays to `{ 0 }`, that's ok -- but it's clearly not necessary in this case. If you mean that the compiler should do it automatically, that just not how it's defined.

Comment: @2501 why?  Why not initialize them with 0xFF?  If the local was 100MB, would you stil want it initialized every time, just to be overwritten in the next line by a disk read?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not needed in this case, in the sense that it has no effect on the output. It might be needed in some similar cases.

```
char dest[100];
```

This defines `dest` as a local array of 100 `char`s. Its initial value is garbage. It *could* have been written as:

```
char dest[100] = "";
```

or

```
char dest[100] = { 0 };
```

but none of those are necessary because `dest` is assigned a value before it's used.

```
strcpy(src, "This is tutorialspoint.com");
strcpy(dest, src);
```

This copies the string contained in `src` into the array `dest`. It copies the 26 characters of `"This is tutorialspoint.com"` plus 1 additional character, the terminating `'\0;` that marks the end of the string. The previous contents of the `dest` array are ignored. (If we were using `strcat()`, it would matter, because `strcat()` has to find a `'\0'` in the destination before it can start copying.)

Without the `memset()` call, the remaining 73 bytes of `dest` would be garbage -- but that wouldn't matter, because we never look at anything past the `'\0'` at `dest[26]`.

If, for some reason, we decided to add something like:

```
printf("dest[99] = '%c'\n", dest[99]);
```

to the program, then the `memset()` would matter. But since the purpose of `dest` is to hold a *string* (which is by definition terminated by a `'\0'` null character), that wouldn't be a sensible thing to do. Perfectly legal, but not sensible.

Answer (score 1):

the posted code could skip the initialization via `memset()`.

A time it really becomes useful is when debugging and you use the debugger to display the contents of the variable.

Another time to use `memset()` is when allocating something like an array of pointers, which might not all be set to point to something specific, like more allocated memory.

Then when passing those pointers to 'free()`the unused pointers are set to NULL, so will not cause a crash when passed to`free()`