# String prints some gibberish at the end, I must be incorrectly creating a string in C

Tags: c

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm pretty sure I'm accessing memory I shouldn't be considering that the print statement is printing gibberish at the end.

Heres where I create my `args` struct.

```
char pureMessage[80];
FILE *file = popen("fortune","r");
if(fread(pureMessage, 80, 1, file) == 0) {
    if(feof(file) == 0) {
        perror("errorfread");
    }
}
strcpy(args->message, pureMessage);
put(args,clnt);
```

Heres how I print it to console: `printf("Client PUT: %s\n", args->message);`

Heres args struct

```
struct rpc_args {
    char action[20];
    char id[80];
    char message[80];
};

program DATABASE {
    version ASSIGNMENT_7 {
        rpc_args ACTION(struct rpc_args) = 1;
    } = 1;
} = 0x20fff100;
```

Comment: HInt: `pureMessage` needs to be null-terminated to be used as _string_.

Comment: `"fortune"` is a text stream. In that case, consider `fgets` to read lines of text instead of `fread`, which is used to read binary data of a fixed size.

Comment: `strcpy(args->message, pureMessage);` is probably your first problem if `pureMessage` is not null terminated.

Comment: That, or the message is 80 characters or longer. Naïve fix: [use `memset`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901038/the-necessity-to-memset-with-0-in-a-toy-example) to clear the `pureMessage` first. Better fix: read one character less with the `fread` and test if it reached its maximum.

Comment: @MOehm I tried `if(fgets(pureMessage, 80, file) != NULL) ` and it immediately resulted in seg fault.

Comment: Your `file` may be null. You don't check whether your `popen` call actually suceeds. Other than that, the call should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcpy()` is unsafe if the memory buffer you copy from (in this case a byte sequence from your file) isn't null-terminated. You need another byte for the null character at the end, so

- either you read only 79 characters with `fread()`
- or you make `char message[80]` in the struct you write into to `char message[81]` - then it has space for the additional null character at the end
- or you use `strncpy()` or `memcpy()` instead of `strcpy()` if you don't want the message in the struct to be null-terminated.

In the first two cases, you have several options again to ensure a null character at the end

- insert `pureMessage[79] = '\0'` after the line `char
  pureMessage[80];` (or 80 and 81, if you want to make the buffer 1
  char longer)
- use `strcat()` instead of `strcpy()` and insert a `pureMessage[0] =
  '\0'` before the `strcat()` call.

Comment: "*use `strcat()` instead of `strcpy()` and insert a `pureMessage[0] =
   '\0'` before the `strcat()` call.*" does this make sense? :-S

Comment: look at strcat() reference. it starts inserting at the first null char and appends a null char, that's how you use strcat normally. has the advantage that you don't have to calculate where to put the null char beforehand, because it always comes at the beginning.